# Is the list append feature a feature of the array data structure?

Tags: arrays, data-structures

The array data structure has the [following features](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Arrays/arrays.html):

> Here is the list of most important array features you must know (i.e.
>   be able to program)
>
> - copying and cloning
> - insertion and deletion
> - searching and sorting

I am wondering, for the list data type, which can be used for the array data structure, is the append method considered a feature of the array data structure, per the insertion and deletion bullet point?

Comment: "which can be used for the array data structure" --- what does this mean?

Comment: list data type i.e. a = [1,2,3]

Comment: I mean - what does the whole phrase mean? Lists and arrays are different data types.

Comment: But, can a list be used to represent an array?

Comment: It cannot - they have different performance characteristics.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that it isn't. I would argue that it is entirely the feature of a list to be able to programmatically append, remove, insertAt, etc. Arrays do not require any functionality other than being a collection of similar types, and in some cases merely a collection of things.

For instance, as referenced [in this C article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Arrays) we can see that an array is a collection of similar types. These arrays have no given functionality, and in fact there is no standard, given, way to add or remove to/from them.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally speaking, appending an element to a list is the same as inserting it at the end.

That being said: You seem to have got the concepts of arrays and lists backwards:

- A **list** is typically defined as any kind of data structure which can store an ordered group of things.
- An **array** is something more specific. It's typically defined as a data structure which is made up of a fixed number of objects in memory, stored one after another. Java's array type (e.g. `int[]`) works this way, for instance.

The web page you are referring to is not helping matters. It's very confusingly written; I'd recommend that you look for another, better reference.